# Integer solutions to $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n| = m$

Tags: combinatorics

Looking for the number of integer solutions to $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n| = m$

Stars and bars can easily give the number of positive or even non-negative solutions, but the full number of solutions accounting for positive and negative solutions is proving trickier for me.

Answer (score 6):

Stars and bars give that there are $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ solutions where $k$ numbers are positive, and the rest are zero. Each of these give rise to $2^k$ integer solutions. Thus the total number of solutions is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n2^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-1}{k-1}
$$
I don't know whether there is a closed form of this, although I will try to find one if I get time.

Comment: brilliant! I'd suggest that should be $$
\sum_{k=1}^{\mathrm{min}(m,n)}2^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{m-1}{k-1}
$$ though. Will leave this open for a little while longer in the hope that a closed form can be found.

Comment: @John Precisely because we want to avoid having to use that kind of $\min$, the convention is that $\binom nk=0$ if $k>n$ or $k<0$.